# How to create dynamic graphs in Mediawiki

Tags: filter, mediawiki, wiki, dynamic-data

Our company has an internal wiki powered by MediaWiki. We are planning to create a wiki page to post some operational data in the form of graphs. Im wondering is it possible to create the following in the wiki page?

1. Create combo boxes like frequency of data (last month/last quarter)
2. Create button to generate graph
3. If possible a calendar to select data range
4. A dynamically generated graph based on the above filters

Does wiki pages allow creation of these objects and generation of graphs based on the filters dynamically? Any references to do this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a custom-built extension. See [Extension: Wiretap](https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Wiretap) as an example (the source code is on GitHub). Basically you query the database using PHP and add it into the HTML source. Then you can use JavaScript to plot with d3.

Answer (score 0):

(Nearly) Interactive graphs are possible with MediaWiki, but only, if you install [the Graph extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Graph), which is a bit more difficult to work with. However, there are some good tutorials and demos on the linked extension page and subpages. I'm not quite sure, if all of your use cases can be implemented with the graphs extension, as I'm not that familiar with this extension.

Comment: Thank you. Can we create combo boxes and buttons? Can I write logic to display graphs based on the filter settings? Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think so, as the extension doesn't seem to provide these logics :(